# Rails plugin test case is not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, plugins

I created a Rails plugin and I wrote a test case for that, But unfortunately when I run the tests for the plugin my test methods are not executing, and it's not giving an error as well.

Following is my Test class

```
require 'test_helper'

class OpticlaimLoggerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "check_null" do
    assert_not_nil nil
  end
end
```

Then I go to the rails plugin path '`vendor/plugins/<plugin name>`' and run

```
bundle exec rake test
```

But nothing happens (as I'm expecting this test case to fail), following is the console output

```
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I"lib:lib:test" -I"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib" "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/**/*_test.rb"
```

And I found that, the execution is not executing the '`check_null`', method

The following is my Ruby setup

1. Ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
2. Rails 2.3.8
3. gem version 1.8.11

Comment: Nothing on this, huh? Ping, i'm having what looks like the same problem, and similar specs - i am using Bundler as well.